# How can I share my Stack Overflow reputation on Facebook?

Tags: support, reputation, flair, sharing

I would like to share my Stack Overflow reputation on Facebook

Is that supported already? If not, is there any plan to implement this in the future?

**BTW. Thank you, Alex Miller! Giving me a "Stack Exchange T-Shirt" yesterday meeting :)**

Comment: Did you try sharing your flair by getting the code from your profile by clicking the "flair" link?  What have you tried to do already? This will help give us some context of where you're lost and where you need help. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at your flair page:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/877644/inspiredjw/flair

> ### InspiredJW > Flair
>
> #### What is it?
>
> It's a piece of valuable flair<sup>tm</sup> you can place on any website to show off your user profile!
>
> [image: flair]  [image: flair]  [image: flair]
>
> ...
>
> ### How do I use it?
>
> Simply copy and paste the below HTML snippet wherever you want to show off your Stack Overflow flair:
>
> `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/877644/inspiredjw">
>   <img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/877644.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for InspiredJW at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for InspiredJW at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers">
>   </a>`
>
> <sup>(to change the theme, add `?theme=clean` or `?theme=dark` or `?theme=hotdog` to the end of the image URL)</sup>
>
> … and for the combined Stack Exchange flair:
>
> `<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/470439">
>   <img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/470439.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for InspiredJW on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for InspiredJW on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites">
>   </a>`

[image: profile for gnat on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: how do i use it in twitter ...

Comment: I'm confused, the snippet doesn't convert to the flair on facebook...

Comment: Facebook doesn't convert markup to flair.